# SMS Message Template in Word?

Tags: microsoft-word, templates, writing

A client of mine is writing a book in which he needs to display modern style SMS Messages in the book. He is writing with MS Word.

Is it possible to make a "SMS/Chat Message" template which he can reuse throughout the book?

I'm wondering whether it would be an idea for him to write in another way, perhaps based on HTML and CSS instead of Word.

Comment: I'd use HTML/CSS: [https://superuser.com/questions/1275141/how-to-wrap-every-paragraph-with-a-custom-text-box-in-word](https://superuser.com/questions/1275141/how-to-wrap-every-paragraph-with-a-custom-text-box-in-word)

Comment: @cnread Right. Maybe I could write a simple web app that generates the HTML/CSS for him. Perhaps also render it out as an image as well.